# Field return count of another table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I need that `read_books`field (in Purchased), return the `Rating` objects count.

Should return the number of objects according to the filter of the same collections of each book in `Rating` and the same user.

I don't know how to do this because `Rating` and `Purchased` are not directly dependent.

rating/models.py

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    rating = models.IntergerField(default=0)
```

book/models.py

```
class Books(models.Model):      
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    book = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

collection/models.py

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

purchased_collections/models.py

```
class Purchased(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now) 
    read_books = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**AFTER APPLICATION OF @ruddra 'S RESPONSE**

The first option:

```
    def read_books(self):
        return Rating.objects.filter(user=self.user, book__collection=self.collection).count()
```

worked in `models.py`. But I wanted to run this function only when the user logs in. 
So I tried to put it in `def login (request):` in views.py, 
but, it is not based on a `class`, I can't use the (self). Always returns the error `name 'self' is not defined.`

So, I tried the secont @ruddra 's suggestion:

```
purchases = Purchased.objects.annotate(read_books=Count('collection__books__rating', filter=Q(collection__books__rating__user=F('user'))))
for item in purchases:
    print(item.read_books)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from .login import login_user

from purchased.models import Purchased
from rating.models import Rating
from collection.models import Collection
from book.models import Books

from django.db.models import F, Count, Q

def login(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            login_status = login_user(request)
            if login_status != 1:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid')
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in')

                purchases = Purchased.objects.annotate(read_books=Count('collection__books__rating', filter=Q(collection__books__rating__user=F('user'))))
                for item in purchases:
                   print(item.read_books)


                return redirect('home')

        else:
            return render(request, 'users/login.html')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'You are already logged in')
        return redirect('index')
```

but ever return error: `NameError: name 'collection__books__rating__user' is not defined.`

The problem is to be able to filter each `ratings` objects by their own `collection`. Using (self) in `models.py` it works perfectly, but I can't make it work without (self).

Any other suggestions to make this count run only when the user logs in?

Comment: `book = models.ForeignKey(Statement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)` is it accurate or should it be `book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)`?

Comment: Yes, You are correct. Sorry. I aready edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming you meant `book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)` in `Rating` model:*

You can use a property method to return the count:

```
class Purchased(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now) 

    @property
    def read_books(self):
        return Rating.objects.filter(user=self.user, book__collection=self.collection).count()
```

Or better, if you use [**`annotation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation)(which will reduce DB hits and you can use that for querying):

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, Q

purchases = Purchased.objects.annotate(read_books=Count('collection__books__rating', filter=Q(collection__books__rating__user=F('user'))))

for item in purchases:
    print(item.read_books)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'collection__statement__progress__user' is not defined. What's wrong?

Comment: The same error occurred. I edited the question to try to clarify the situation.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, if you are using `Book` as the foreign key related model, then you can find out the count by:

```
class Purchased(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now) 
    read_books = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self):
        self.read_books = Rating.objects.filter(user=self.user, book__in=self.collection.books_set).count()
        return super().save()
```

Comment: I just wanted to run this function at user login. I tried to put this function in view.py along with the login function but it didn't work and didn't return any error. So, it just works on models. What can I do to just run this function when the user logs in?